# Is the integral $\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{\arctan x}{x}dx$ convergent?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I was given this integral:

$$\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}dx$$

As the title says, I have to find out whether it is convergent or not.
So far, I have tried integrating by parts and substituting ${\arctan(x)}$, and neither got me anywhere.

Comment: What is $\operatorname{atg}$? Is it the inverse tangent function?

Comment: What is `atgx`? Is it $a \tan(x)$ or $\arctan(x)$ or something else?

Comment: Fixed the question.My bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\operatorname{atg}$ means the inverse tangent function, then your integral does not converge.

One can see that $\arctan x\ge \pi/4$ if $x\ge 1$, so $$\frac{\arctan x}{x}\ge \frac{\pi}{4x}$$ for $x\ge 1$. Since $\int_1^\infty\frac{\pi}{4x}dx$ diverges, so does $\int_1^\infty\frac{\arctan x}{x}dx$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\arctan(e^t)\,dt$$ but this integrand does not vanish.

Comment: Provided that by "does not vanish" you mean that $\liminf\limits_{t\to\infty} \arctan e^t>0$.

Comment: @Gae.S.: on an infinite section, $\arctan(e^t)>1$.